# About compiling Java through terminal javac

Tags: java, compiler-errors, classpath

I am a Java newbie, just started learning it in college, and my class is using NetBeans but I'd like to use VSCode.

The professor told us that every Java file should start with:
package nameofthepackage
So that Java knows to which package the class (file) I created belongs to.

So I always create this structure:
I create a folder with the name of the main class, and inside this folder I make a src folder that will store the Java files. Eg:
MyJavaProject/src/MyJavaProject.java

I always name the main .Java file the same as the project folder name.

And when I compile I use javac with the -cp parameter to specify that the src folder is the classpath folder, where it should look for the .Java files I create.
I also always tell javac to compile all the files inside the src folder, using the * wildcard.

The issue is that with this line on top of my .Java files, javac compiles all the files, but I can't execute the bytecode because it complains it can't find the classes I created, even the main one.

As Soon as I remove the package line from the top of the files, I can compile and run the code.

So far it's good, but for any more complex projects this is gonna be really annoying.

Any ideas how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you execute the code with package.class ? For more complex projects I would use an IDE like eclipse.

Comment: I would suggest you research and learn how to use Makefiles for java if you don't want to use a IDE. There are other build systems, but Makefiles will probably be the simplest to learn and start with on a small project

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the full name (with package) of the class that contains the main function.

Assuming the class `MyJavaProject` is the one containing your main, that would be:

```
java nameofthepackage.MyJavaProject
```

This is assuming you built it with

```
javac -d . MyJavaProject.java
```

It would create your target class in a directory structure like:

```
nameofthepackage\MyJavaProject.class
```